# how to use email logger packer in laravel?

Tags: email, logging, laravel-5

I am using

> juniorb2ss/laravel-email-logger

package in

> Laravel 5.2

For email logging, i have read its documentation but there is not much about implementation.
I have install it but need suggestion to use. should i explicitly put message into db or this package will do on it self?
Package link is

```
https://github.com/juniorb2ss/laravel-email-logger
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

> https://github.com/shvetsgroup/laravel-email-database-log

and for laravel 5.2 after installing please change in file:

> Path :
>   vendor\shvetsgroup\laravel-email-database-log\src\ShvetsGroup\LaravelEmailDatabaseLog\LaravelEmailDatabaseLogServiceProvider.php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;

Replace public function boot() with public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)

Replace parent::boot(); with `parent::boot($events);`

and if don't want to use migrations please comment following line:

`$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../../database/migrations');`